# Word Addin Typescript React How to open a file and interact with it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I tried so many ways, went through the existing documentation but I was not able to find how I can open a file, so called my template, which then I need to update from the Addin.

I succeeded to open the file this way:

```
reportDoc = context.application.createDocument(templateFileBase64);
reportDoc.open();
await reportDoc.context.sync();
```

Then I would like to access the new file that open, for example its content controls. Below one example but I tried so many ways.

```
await Word.run(reportDoc, async (reportContext: Word.RequestContext) => {
const allContentControls: Word.ContentControlCollection = reportContext.document.contentControls;
allContentControls.load(['id', 'title', 'tag']);
await reportContext.sync();
allContentControls.items.forEach((CntCtrl) => {
          //To do
   });
});
```

Whatever I do, it is reading the original file where the add-in was initially loaded but not those of the new file that is opened: reportDoc.

If you can help me, I am completely stuck!

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to say more precisely what goes wrong. For example, in place of your "//To do" what happens if you log the control name to the console?

Comment: This is what I wrote here: "Whatever I do, it is reading the original file where the add-in was initially loaded.". In the Ex, loaded Content Controls are those of the original file, not those of the newly opened file.